# Graphical glitches under Windows 10 with up-to-date NVIDIA drivers

Tags: windows-10, laptop, nvidia-geforce

[image]

[image]

The aforementioned pictures are my Windows calculator and my Wi-Fi menu from the start bar.

I'm running on an Alienware 18 laptop. I've got 16 GB RAM, Core i7-4940MX (not overclocked), and two Nvidia GeForce GTX 880Ms in SLI. DirectX is updated, graphics drivers are updated. Windows 10, fully updated. It also regularly happens in Microsoft Office, Visual Studio, and my internet browsers. I can't even describe it well enough to google it properly. Win+X menu displays properly, along with most right-click menus.

Any thoughts or general advice? I can't figure out what is causing it, and nor have any of my coworkers or superuser friends.

Comment: Are all of the programs with the graphical glitches made by microsoft?

Comment: disable nVIDIA optimus for Explorer.exe, shellexperiencehost.exe and sihost.exe so that the Intel HD is used

Comment: 364.72 drivers? [You're not alone.](http://wccftech.com/nvidias-latest-game-ready-driver-allegedly-killing-gpus-plagued-issues/)

Comment: @magicandre1981: No Optimus on this machine. It's an SLI system (two GTX 880M cards), and Optimus is not supported on SLI laptops. Everything is being rendered by the GeForce card(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest NVIDIA graphics drivers as of this writing are broken.

There have been quite a few reports of 364 series drivers causing all sorts of graphical issues. Version 364.72, in particular, [has been widely reported to cause serious graphical defects and even hardware failure](http://wccftech.com/nvidias-latest-game-ready-driver-allegedly-killing-gpus-plagued-issues/). Your best bet is to revert the drivers to 362.00 or earlier.

Comment: Some comments of that article say it's a 1st April joke

Comment: [This Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/4crp3j/warning_avoid_36472_march_28_like_the_plague_its/) was posted before April Fools' Day. See also http://wccftech.com/nvidia-users-beware-latest-drivers-damage-pc/ on issues with earlier drivers in the 364 series. Furthermore, [364.67 has been reported to cause similar issues](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3041484/software/nvidias-new-36467-game-ready-drivers-are-crashing-systems-but-theres-a-fix.html). No matter how you look at it, it's no mere April Fools' prank.